# How to send information from devise user using mailer?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm using devise gem and I want to set up a mailer to send information from user to my gmail account and also the user receive a confirmation.

Answer (score 0):

Please be a bit more specific in the first part of your question. What do you exactly want to do?

For the confirmation, the devise gem has a confimrable module which might help you further. Look here: https://www.rubydoc.info/github/plataformatec/devise/master/Devise/Models/Confirmable